# Passing variables between jython scripts and sharing SQL connection

Tags: python, sql, jython

I have two jython scripts and I have created connection to Oracle database in the 1st script and declared some variables and I want to use that in 2nd script without having to write the getconnection string again in 2nd script and also have to use the data / variables from one script and pass it on to the other.
Global keyword is not working.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: What you want to do is possible, but you'll need to read up on `import` (and understand it) before you can succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is sharing some common values e.g. target server name , you can

1) create a new .py file which contains the variable

```
# common.py
DB=db.company.com
```

2) In your scripts, import the variable from the new .py file

```
from common import DB

...

odbc.connect('SERVER=%s' % DB)
```

These code assumes you put all .py files in the same directory.